# Google Sheets: Update rows of existing Data, on Query Result Change

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where I obtain data (one column, let's say A), for instance  mail addresses, from another sheet with a query (`QUERY` function).

Another column (let's say B) is intended to contain different IDs for each of mail addresses. So, I have a script that attributes to each non-blank on A, a random ID, if this isn't already attributed. I have a button to do that.

My problem is that, if query result change, for instance to have a new row or to have one less row, IDs on column B are no longer consistent with data on column A.

Is there way to update my colum B, on query result change, so IDs are always on correct row, consistently with emails on column A?

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet or provide a sample sheet that replicates the issue.

Comment: @JasonE. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XCSPeXo5rOhBi7Q19fVfPVwF1Z5BBGz8uZgz8MuPXRI/edit?usp=sharing
Here is an example. 'Folha2' "imports" TRUE data from "Folha1". A button allows to give an ID to rows, where ID (collumn B) is not given yet, from a script. I think you can only see and run the script if you login with Google account.
The problem is: if I set one of the FALSE values to TRUE, the data is updated in 'Folha2'. However, IDs remains on the same rows, since they aren't linked to the imported data. There is a way to solve this, since I can't give the IDs in "Folha1"?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches.

1. When you import, you can check if the imported email id already exists on Folha2. If it does, you can skip that row. Or,
2. You could write back the assigned id, to the record on Folha1. Then you can import only those records that are TRUE, and do not have an assigned random id.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way to solve this aside from using Apps Script entirely is to change the format of your sheet/data.

I suggest opting into the 1st option(Apps Script) and write the code by including onEdit() trigger and populate the "Folha2" sheet once an edit in Column B of "Folha1" has been made(ex. Column B of "Folha1" changed from FALSE() to TRUE()). Since this approach does not rely on the QUERY() formula, you can always append new values/data to the first blank row/last row.